# readAsArrayBuffer is extremely slow on mobile

Tags: javascript, filereader

Run the snippet below on desktop browser and select any file over 10MB. You will get read speed around 4MB/s. If you run it on mobile Chrome in android you will get something near 90Kb/s.

Is there a way it can be improved?

p.s.
I'm using sliceFile to send BufferArray over RTCDataChannel from mobile.

```js
function load() {

  function bytesToSize(bytes) {
    var sizes = ['Bytes/s', 'KB/s', 'MB/s', 'GB/s', 'TB/s'];
    if (bytes < 1) return '';
    var i = parseInt(Math.floor(Math.log(bytes) / Math.log(1024)));
    return Math.round(bytes / Math.pow(1024, i), 2) + ' ' + sizes[i];
  }


  var reader = new window.FileReader();
  var offset = 0;
  var f = window.event.target.files[0];
  proggress.max = f.size;
  reader.onload = read;

  function read() {
    if (offset < f.size) {
      var currentSlice = f.slice(offset, offset + 16384);
      offset += 16384;
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(currentSlice);
      proggress.value = offset;
    }
  }

  var lastOffset = 0;
  setInterval(function () {
    var s = bytesToSize(offset - lastOffset);
    if (s) {
      currSpeed.textContent = s;
    }
    lastOffset = offset;
  }, 1000);
  read();
}
```

```html
<progress id="proggress"></progress>
<div id="currSpeed"></div>
<input type="file" value="click" onchange="load()"/>
```

**UPDATE**:

I ended up with slicing bigger chunks and splitting them manually from ArrayBuffer into required ones.

Comment: I don't know JavaScript. But could you use BufferedReader? It works faster than FileReader.

Comment: which mobile device are you using?

Comment: Android 7.0 Xiaomi mi4c , Snapdragon 808 with internal flash that is not that slow...